# How to optimize search for ideal matches between two ordered slice of structs?

Tags: go, optimization, search, match

I have two slices:

```golang
type MyStruct struct {
  Id int
  field1 int
  field2 int
}

var sliceA []*MyStruct
var sliceB []*MyStruct
```

What I want is to find ideal matches from two slices.

The acceptable criteria is `field1` and `field2` can be respectively matched in a specific range (for example, low range 10, top range 20).
Also, one matched element can be matched for a different one (like many to many).

What I tried:

```golang
startIndex := 0
lengthOfB := len(sliceB)

leftBorder := 10
rightBorder := 20


for _, a := range sliceA {
  for i := startIndex; i < lengthOfB; i++ {
    if sliceB[i].field1 < a.field1 - leftBorder {
      // if it is less than the minimum limit then for the
      // next element from sliceA I don't need to check it.
      startIndex++

      continue
    }

    if sliceB[i].field1 > a.field1 + rightBorder {
      // if it is greater than the maximum limit then it is
      // time to go to the next element from sliceA. 
      break
    }

    // check other conditions
    if /* matched*/ {
      // add match details into a different slice
      // then continue the loop
    }
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** both slices, `sliceA` and `sliceB` are ordered by `field1` in ascending order before the loop.

The time complexity roughly `O(n*m)` and it is too slow (obviously).

Comment: What was done is improved memory allocation - adding new elements into match list was changed and it had good effect on timing.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over one slice and binary search into the other slice.

```
for _, a := range sliceA {
    b := binarySearch(sliceB, a.field1)
    if matched(b.field1, a.field1) {
        // Whatever you want to do
    } 
}
```

This will be `O(n log m)`. If `n` and `m` and different sizes, iterate over the shorter one.

Comment: For one-to-one matching yes, it is fine. But for many-to-many one, no, unfortunately.

Comment: @Gasimoff clarify what you mean. Include examples.

Comment: I already mentioned in the main question, before "try" section

Comment: @Gasimoff your terminology is unclear and you include no examples. Do you mean you also want all A ~in B in addition to B ~in A?